# Azure - Move an webapp to an another appservice plan - Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

Hi is there a powershell script for moving a web app to an another app service plan who is not in the same resourcegroup. Or can we create a web app where the app service plan is not in the same resource group.

```
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroup -Name $testWebAppName -location $location `
    -AppServicePlan $appServicePlan01
```

This script create a new webapp  and a new app service plan even there is one exist with the same name. so in case when a want to move the problem resiste the same i cant move it to an existing app service plan.

```
Set-AzWebApp -Name $WebAppName -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroup `
    -AppServicePlan $appServicePlan02
```

is there a powershell cmdlet for doing this or do I move the webapp trough the portal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The region in which your app runs is the region of the App Service plan it's in. However, you cannot change an App Service plan's region. If you want to run your app in a different region, one alternative is app cloning. Cloning makes a copy of your app in a new or existing App Service plan in any region.

It can be accomplished by using the Azure Resource Manager version of the PowerShell cmdlet to create a new app with the `-SourceWebApp` option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning#cloning-an-existing-app

Comment: Thanks but is there a solution without cloning my app service plan will be  in the same region and in the same resource group like before. From the portal when you change the service plan there is no downtime but if i clone the app there will be probably one. But thanks again for the answer it helped me for an another think cheers.